# Scrutinizer: install custom composer packages?

Tags: php, scrutinizer

I have a Github project in Scrutinizer, that has an optional recommended package in its composer.json.

I would like to install this optional package during the Scrutinizer build, but could not find any information on how to do so in the Scrutinizer config. While the package is optional, Scrutinizer detects a number of bugs because the dependency is not present, and some of the unit tests will only run if it is present.

Is it possible to run custom composer commands, or to have additional composer packages installed?

The related package is [Mistralys/application-utils](https://scrutinizer-ci.com/g/Mistralys/application-utils/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking through scrutinizer configurations of other projects, I was able to find out how to run custom composer commands.

To require additional packages, these can be added in the dependencies:

```yaml
build:
    dependencies:
        before:
            - composer require vendor/package-name:version
```

It is also possible to override scrutinizer's composer command entirely, for example to run a script:

```yaml
build:
    dependencies:
        override:
            - composer run-script scriptname
```

In my case, because the suggested package also requires the source package back (cyclic dependency), I had to set the root version, like this:

```yaml
build:
    dependencies:
        override:
            - COMPOSER_ROOT_VERSION=dev-master composer require mistralys/application-localization:dev-master
```